# Python Dataframe - filter NoneType values

Tags: python, json, pandas, nonetype

Am using a df created from JSON data, with pd.DataFrame.from_dict(EventList, orient='index'), some values in the currentEvent column are shown with a value None.  I'm trying to filter them out:

currentEvent == 'None' or
currentEvent == ''

Neither works.  When I use type() on one of the cells, it a value: NoneType

Trying to figure out how to filter out rows with these values from the df?

Comment: Something with  `isna()`?

Comment: `currentEvent == 'None'` will only look for the literal string `"None"`. Can you show a [mcve] of what you are trying to do here?